# Insert database in CI 3 doesn't work

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

H, I want to ask, why my code below doesn't work. I have been googling and not find the answer

```
public function insertComment($commentArray=array()) {
    try {
        $this->db->trans_start();

        $name = $this->db->escape($commentArray['name']);
        $email = $this->db->escape($commentArray['email']);
        $message = $this->db->escape($commentArray['message']);
        $blogID = $this->db->escape($commentArray['blogID']);

        $sql = "insert into comment(email,comment,createdon,status,blogID,name) "
. " values($email,$message,now(),0,$blogID,$name)";

        error_log($sql);
        $this->db->query($sql);

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
        } else {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
        }

    } catch (Exception $ex) {

  }
}
```

but if I use native way to insert into database, it work correctly

```
public function insertComment($commentArray=array()) {
        try {

            mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
            mysql_select_db('yungfei');

             $sql = "insert into client(client_name) values('xxxx')";

             mysql_query($sql);
             error_log($sql);

} catch (Exception $ex) {

    }
    }
```

My databse config:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default']['dsn'] = 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=database_name';

    $db['default'] = array(
            'dsn'   => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yungfei',
            'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => TRUE,
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
```

There is something I miss? I use Code Igniter 3. Help please me thanks

Comment: are you getting any error??

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = array(
        'title' => 'My title',
        'name'  => 'My Name',
        'date'  => 'My date'
);

$this->db->insert('table', $data);
```

this is simply structure to insert data into db, try this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function insertComment($commentArray = array()) {
    try {
        $this->db->trans_begin();

        $name    = $this->db->escape($commentArray['name']);
        $email   = $this->db->escape($commentArray['email']);
        $message = $this->db->escape($commentArray['message']);
        $blogID  = $this->db->escape($commentArray['blogID']);

        $sql = "insert into comment(email,comment,createdon,status,blogID,name) values($email,$message,now(),0,$blogID,$name)";

        error_log($sql);
        $this->db->query($sql);

        $this->db->trans_complete();

        if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE) {
            $this->db->trans_rollback();
        }
        else {
            $this->db->trans_commit();
        }
    }
}
```

A quote from the CodeIgniter manual page: "Make sure to use $this->db->trans_begin() when running manual transactions, NOT $this->db->trans_start()."